# ¿De que manera se puede encriptar una contraseña para una base de datos?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, seguridad

Según he leido SHA-2 no es seguro y hace falta usar una encriptación más fuerte. He visto que en PHP se puede usar `password_hash()`.

¿La salida de esa función sería suficiente encriptación?

Comment: Puedes checar este enlace acerca de [crypt](http://php.net/manual/es/function.crypt.php)

Comment: También te puede interesar leer [OWASP: Password Storage Cheat Sheet](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Password_Storage_Cheat_Sheet)

Comment: md5 ya no es un algoritmo seguro porque fue vulnerado ya hace bastante tiempo, porfavor no uses md5. En la misma pagina que cita Jhousef Flores hay una nota al respecto: Nota: Hash seguro de contraseñas
Dada la velocidad de este algoritmo de hash, se recomienda no utilizar esta función para proteger las contraseñas. Para más información, revise aquí.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

He encontrado una respuesta de Stackoverflow en inglés que me responde a la pregunta [Secure hash and salt for PHP passwords](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/401656/secure-hash-and-salt-for-php-passwords).

La respuesta mas votada dice que no se debe hacer hash con SHA1, MD5 o SHA256 porque los crackers modernos pueden superar los 180 miles de millones de hash por segundo por lo que no les cuesta romperla.

Y la segunda más votada recomienda no escribir nuestro propio mecanismo, sino usar la función de PHP `password_hash()`. Ejemplo de `password_hash()`:

```
$pass = $_POST['password'];    
$passHash = password_hash($pass, PASSWORD_BCRYPT);
```

El algoritmo BCRYPT nos creará una cadena de 72 caracteres como máximo, la cual es distinta cada vez que se codifica, por lo que para comprobar que la contraseña introducida es la correcta debemos usar la función `password_verify()`:

```
password_verify($pass, $passHash)
```

Answer (score 5):

La mejor opción (según el manual de PHP) es utilizar **password_hash()** para encriptar la clave y recuperarla luego de la base de datos mediante el uso de **password_verify()**

Si bien la opción de incluir un $salt propio está incluida en la función password_hash(), se recomienda no utilizar un salt y dejar eso en manos de PHP que genera uno en forma automática y que resulta mucho más seguro que cualquier tipo de salt que podamos incluir por nuestra cuenta, del modo que se nos ocurra. 
De hecho, en varias partes del manual de PHP se ruega encarecidamente NO usar un salt propio para las claves volcadas a esta función ya que debilitarían la fortaleza de la misma.
(De hecho en la versión 7 de PHP ya se considera obsoleta esta opción y arrojará un error en tiempo de ejecución).

En cuanto al parámetro "cost" que se puede añadir, sí resulta una medida accesoria de seguridad, pero es necesario tenerla en cuenta de acuerdo al servidor donde se está utilizando dicha función debido a la carga de trabajo sobre el servidor para crear un hash de clave más robusto.

El código sugerido es:

```
$opciones = [  'cost' => 12, ];

password_hash($tu_propia_clave, PASSWORD_BCRYPT, $opciones);
```

Por lo general, un coste de 12 es bastante seguro y produce una carga de trabajo del servidor que es tolerable (por regla general, en algunos casos será necesario realizar diversas pruebas para evaluar que la "función tome menos de 100 milisegundos en sistemas interactivos." -SIC-).
Si no se indica el array que contiene dicho coste (debe estar sí o sí incluído en un array) su valor es de 10 como valor predeterminado.

El ejemplo para validar la clave recuperada desde la BD contra la que ingresa un usuario, sería algo así:

```
$hash_BD = $objeto_bd->valor_hash_recuperado;

if (password_verify($tu_propia_clave, $hash_BD)) {
    echo '¡La contraseña es válida!';
} else {
    echo 'La contraseña no es válida.'; 
}
```

Como siempre, en caso de requerir más información siempre es mejor ir a la fuente: [PHP.NET - Función password_hash()](http://php.net/manual/es/function.password-hash.php)

[image: Advertencias de PHP.Net al respecto...]

Answer (score 2):

Complementando la respuesta de Carlos Quiroga, una buena posibilidad es utilizar un salt dinámico que se base en la contraseña del usuario. Por ejemplo:

```
<?PHP

$user_pass =  'Mi_Pasw0rd';
$salt = md5($user_pass);
$pasword_encriptado = crypt($user_pass, $salt);

echo $pasword_encriptado;

?>
```

No obstante, guardar la contraseña en la base de datos en forma segura, no es lo único de lo que hay que preocuparse, ya que hay que cubrir distintos flacos de posibles ataques. Una posibilidad es utilizar Token de seguridad creados en forma aleatoria en la página de Login para evitar ataques de tipo CSRF. Este sería un ejemplo muy escueto y simple pero demostrativo de cual es la idea:

```
<HTML> <!-- Formulario de Login-->
<input name="token" id="token" type="hidden" value='<?= md5(time()); ?>'>
</HTML>

<?PHP /*Página de inicio de sesión */

/* Si las credenciales de usuario se validan se abre una sesión y */
/* se agrega el token a la variable $_SESSION .*/

$token              =   crypt($_POST['token']);
$_SESSION["token"]  =   $token;

?>
```

El token se puede almacenar en la base de datos, en la tabla de usuarios y ser comparado en un archivo de seguridad, la particularidad el token es único por usuario y por session

```
<?PHP /*Página de control */
....
$result = $stm->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$token= $result['Token'];
if ($_SESSION["token"] != $token ) {

    header("Location: login.php");
    exit();

}   

?>
```

De esta forma tienes una contraseña de usuario encriptada y una contraseña dinámica que nadie más conoce.

Answer (score 2):

Intenta:

```
$INSERT INTO usuarios VALUES('usuario',SHA('contraseña'));
$INSERT INTO usuarios VALUES('usuario',MD5('contraseña'));
```

Eche un vistazo a este enlace:

http://www.solingest.com/blog/almacenar-contrasenas-en-mysql

Answer (score 1):

¿Cuál es el problema con `SHA-2`? Quizás te refieres que la familía `SHA-1` es vulnerable (así es)
El recomendado como mínimo es `SHA256`. Pero cuanto mejor sea, mejor seguridad tendrás. De hecho, se considera que `SHA512` con `Salt` es muy seguro.

Comment: sha256 es una de las alternativas de sha2, el usario dijo que sha2 no le parece suficientemente seguro (aunque no se por que). https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/SHA-2

Comment: He extendido la respuesta, que quizás no se entendia que quería decir....

Answer (score 0):

prueba `md5($var);` es bastante seguro, puedes leer un poco mas aqui

http://php.net/manual/es/function.md5.php

Comment: Hola Jhousef, gracias por participar en el sitio. Las respuestas que consisten en únicamente un enlace no se consideran de buena calidad. ¿Podrías editar tu respuesta para incluir la información más relevante que se expone en el sitio que enlazas?

Comment: Tal vez para el año que se publico esta respuesta era segura pero actualmente (año 2021) ya no se recomienda, en la documentación dice: 

_No se recomienda utilizar esta función para contraseñas seguras debido a la naturaleza rápida de este algoritmo de «hashing»._

Answer (score -2):

A mi se me ocurre que podrias grabar un bloque de ceros o otro caracter y encriptarlo con el modulo mcrypt de php y cuando el usuario coloque una contraseña el programa simplemente revisa si el bloque queda en el caracter original

Comment: Nunca inventes tu propio algoritmo de encriptación.